# ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found:

Tags: solidity, erc-20, error, parser, bscscan

I keep getting this error, would be really cool to get help. I've heard that I need to install a program, forgot which but I'm not so sure that's a great idea to start with and is not the fix to this issue. I've tried to verify the contract but been without results.

Here's the issue:

```
: ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> myc:4:1:
  |
4 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And this is my code (took away the name for security reasons):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract secret is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialsupply) public ERC20 ("secret", "secret") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

Comment: What tool are you using to compile the contract? Hardhat, Web3j, Truffle, ... The error says it is trying to open a file with "@openzeppelin/contracts/..." and it can't find it.

Comment: Someone told me to install openzeppelin into the contract and that's how far I am right now. And about tools, As far I know I'm doing a smart contract from remix.ethereum and a tool I would think is namely web3 but I'm not sure.  I'm pretty much thinking it is. What advice would you have for me right now? This step has been a problem for me, so going through this would both help me and be a knowledge opportunity. Would be cool @Ismael if you could advise me on what to do next to solve this. Much thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

import "OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.8.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

'@' is not required anymore you can specify the same in your .yaml files(remappings).

Answer (score 0):

To import an OpenZepplin contract from Remix you have to import using the full github URL.

For example to import contracts from v4.4.0 this will work.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.4.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";


contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("NOMNOM", "MON") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, I did that: I have deployed it and it's same as yours and even made it to an exchange, the only problem I have now is getting it verified and I keep getting this problem:  File import callback not supported 
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Mooncoin is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialsupply) public ERC20 ("secret", "secret") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialsupply);
    }
} What initiative should I do now, I'm very much confused.

Comment: As for the environment, probably a tool, it's injected web 3, I have used. Is there a special command or initiative I should take to verify the smart contract? As I said before I'm very much thankful for your help @Ismael.

Comment: @Feynman Remix has a plugin for verification on Etherscan if that doesn't work you should try asking a new question.

Comment: Cheers for the help again. But this token is on the bscscan and not etherscan @Ismael.

Comment: About import -> Don’t import from master , choose a tag @Feynman

Comment: I'm getting this error in polygonscan trying to verify my contract.