# How do i install: $ npm install @openzeppelin/contracts - is it on remix? Easy solution

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, openzeppelin, bscscan

This may sound stupid but would the team or anyone give advice on how to install it in the first place: Is it on the remix.etherum? If not which and what should I do to be able to install it?

Is it intended to deploy the token again with new code in the remix? By myself, is this not the solution and not the way to install @openzeppelin/contracts.

Basically, how do I install $ npm install @openzeppelin/contracts

This is the problem I have. There is a very easy solution, but as I'm very much new to smart contracts, It would be cool to get a piece of advice on how to fix this issue.

Where, and if so how do i do it?

Comment: You need to get the contract directly from GitHub, but not from main branch, choose a tag and get them from there

Comment: @MajdTL - Thankful for your advice, but could you be more specific: which tag and what should I do after I choose a tag (how do I choose a tag), where should I start to install openzeppelin/contracts. For now, I assume that should get the contract directly from Github, whom I have done, but clueless on the next step. Would be cool to get another piece of advice from you. Cheers, Will do a tutorial on youtube for other after you give me this advice on how to fix this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is not possible to "install" OpenZeppelin in remix (yet). I thought this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/114385 was good enough. Remix is good for quick task if you want something more serious I'd recommend hardhat, brownie, web3j, truffle, etc.